# Loop count != list.Count - Populating List<string> in new threads

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Why is the result (list.Count) of the following code always something around 18100 and not 19000 as expected?

```
    var list = new List<string>(19000);
    List<Task> tl = new List<Task>(19000);

    for (int q = 0; q < 19000; q++)
    {
        tl.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var k = "something";
            list.Add(k);
        }));
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tl.ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine(list.Count);
```

Comment: `List<T>` is not thread-safe.  You can't do that.

Comment: So I have to implement locking a seperate class that contains access to this list, right?

Comment: @Legends Doing so would be pointless.  You'd just be serializing everything, resulting in it doing way more work.  The solution is to *not parallelize this* in the first place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the `List<T>` is not thread safe.

### Task Parallelism

You could work with [thread-safe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) collections in the [`System.Collections.Concurrent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx) and use the type [`ConcurrentBag<>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx). Try using this:

```
var list = new ConcurrentBag<string>();

List<Task> tl = new List<Task>(19000);

for (int q = 0; q < 19000; q++)
{
    tl.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        var k = "something";
        list.Add(k);
    }));
}

Task.WaitAll(tl.ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(list.Count);
```

There are other thread-safe types like `ConcurrentQueue<>`, `ConcurrentStack<>`, etc.

### Dealing with Non Thread-Safe objects  - lock(object)

On the other hand, you could use the [`lock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) keyworkd to block other threads to access the same block of statements. In this case, you could use the `List<T>` and non-thread-safe objects, for sample:

The object must be visible for all threads, so, you could declare it on a class scope, for sample:

```
private static object _sync = new object();
```

After it, try lock this instance when you need to modify, for sample:

```
var list = new List<string>(19000);

List<Task> tl = new List<Task>(19000);

for (int q = 0; q < 19000; q++)
{
    tl.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
       lock(_sync)
       {
          var k = "something";
          list.Add(k);
       }
    }));
}

Task.WaitAll(tl.ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(list.Count);
```

Comment: Creating a whole bunch of threads to do work, only to then synchronize them all such that no more than one can ever do any work, is actively unproductive.  The solution to the problem isn't a `lock`, it's to not parallelize the work in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

The `List<T>` Class isn't thread safe see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

## Thread Safety

Public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

It is safe to perform multiple read operations on a List, but issues can occur if the collection is modified while it’s being read. To ensure thread safety, lock the collection during a read or write operation. To enable a collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own synchronization. For collections with built-in synchronization, see the classes in the System.Collections.Concurrent namespace. For an inherently thread–safe alternative, see the ImmutableList class.

Answer (score 2):

`List(T)` is not thread-safe.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

> Public static members of this type are thread safe. Any instance
>   members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

As a result assigned to it from multiple threads is not guaranteed to produce the desired results.

Comment: Does it mean, that if I make the list static 
    `static List<string> list = new List<string>();`
that it should work? I tried it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: No it is referring to static members of the List(T) class which is not relevant to your issue. You should use the concurrent collections as suggested by Felipe Oriani for multi-threading as you are accessing the list from potentially more than one thread.